How to find Resistor value form voltage drop?
How can I find resistor values form voltage drop across the resistor I needed?
5V DC supply will get convenient into 2.3 V and goes GPIO of Controller and LED is connected to indicate the supply is on
I want find value of resistor if the voltage drop is 1.9V and 0.7V for R1 and R2

I am not able to understand how you can get 2.3V on the MCU GPIO net. You will get 2.4+0.7 = 3.1V isn't it? What current do you need to flow in the LED to get the brightness you need?

What current is the 2.4V LED Vf specced at?

@sai Current for led 8 to 12mA

As mentioned in a comment, the 2.3 V voltage value does not make sense in your schematic.  Separate from that, here is how to calculate the resistor values.
To start, you select the LED current.  For a typical small LED, this is usually around 10 mA to 20 mA, although some high-brightness LEDs need only 2mA to 5 mA.
Once you select the current, and you already have determined the desired voltage drops, use Ohm's Law to calculate the resistances.
Usually, the first-pass calculation will yield resistor values that are not standard ones you can buy.  For example, if you choose an LED current of 10 mA, then the two resistors calculate out to be 1900 ohms and 700 ohms; neither of these are "normal" parts.
The next step is to start substituting the nearest standard values, calculate the current, use that new current to calculate the individual voltage drops, and see how far the desired output voltage shifts.  It can take two or three rounds of this calculating to come up with the best fit resistor values.  Don't get frustrated - everybody has gone through this.

thanks very helpful

It is very easy to calculate the R values based on the current that you want to have in the LED. R = Vdrop/ ILED.
Do also consider a case where the diode could be faulty and is high impedance. You will be feeding 5V to the MCU GPIO. If this is a concern, one solution would be to move the resistors below the diode as shown.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You can then choose the voltage drops across R1 & R2 that you need. In this case, if the LED is faulty i.e., high impedance, the voltage to the MCU GPIO will be 0V.
Alternatively, you can use 2 branches. One branch with LED and resistor for optical indication of the availability of +5V and another branch with just a resistor divider to connect to the MCU GPIO.

simulate this circuit
Here R1 value will be (5-Vf of LED)/ILED
R2 and R3 values can be chosen based on the GPIO voltage needed and the current that you can afford in that branch. For eg., R2 can be 2M ohm and R3 2.4M ohm.

thank you very helpful

You'll no doubt get simpler answers than this, but I wanted to show you all the details of the solution. The long, formal answer, is that we have three laws which together to describe the state of the circuit. One of those laws is Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL), which tells us how voltages across various elements in series add up. In your case, the voltages across R1, R2 and D1 must add up to equal the voltage across the 5V supply V1:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The three voltages \$V_{R1}\$, \$V_{R2}\$ and \$V_{D1}\$, across R1, R2 and D1 respectively are shown on the voltmeters, and we are interested in choosing values of R1 and R2 that achieve these figures. Algebraically KVL here says:
$$ V_{R1} + V_{R2} + V_{D1} = 5V $$
To have an "output" at X of \$V_X = 3.1V\$ relative to the 0V "ground", then again according to KVL the sum of voltages across D1 and R2 must be 3.1V:
$$ V_{D1} + V_{R2} = 3.1V $$
You already know LED voltage, giving us a third equation:
$$ V_{D1} = 2.4V $$
The next law at work is Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL). In a simple loop like this KCL tells us that current in every component is the same, \$I=1mA\$, in the same way water flow around a closed loop of pipes, pumps and other stuff, with no junctions anywhere for water to leave or enter, must be the same everywhere. It's necessary for you to choose current \$I\$ that you intend to flow, because this determines LED brightness. Let's say you settle on 1mA, as shown on the ammeter above:
$$ I=1mA $$
Lastly, we need to use Ohm's law to relate voltages \$V_{R1}\$ and \$V_{R2}\$ across the resistors to the current \$I\$ through them:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= I \times R_1 \\ \\
V_{R2} &= I \times R_2 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
These are the conditions we have established, then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} + V_{R2} + V_{D1} &= 5V \\ \\
V_{D1} + V_{R2} &= 3.1V \\ \\
V_{D1} &= 2.4V \\ \\
I &= 1mA \\ \\
V_{R1} &= I \times R_1 \\ \\
V_{R2} &= I \times R_2 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now solve to find R1 and R2:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} + V_{R2} + V_{D1} &= 5V \\ \\
I \times R_1 + I \times R_2 + 2.4V &= 5V \\ \\
1mA \times R_1 + 1mA \times R_2 &= 5V - 2.4V \\ \\
1mA (R_1 + R_2) &= 2.6V \\ \\
R_1 + R_2 = \frac{2.6V}{1mA} \\ \\
R_1 + R_2 = 2.6k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we know what the two resistances add up to, find out how that total of 2600Ω is distributed between them:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{D1} + V_{R2} &= 3.1V \\ \\
2.4V + I R_2 &= 3.1V \\ \\
2.4V + 1mA\times R_2 &= 3.1V \\ \\
1mA\times R_2 &= 3.1V - 2.4V \\ \\
R_2 &= \frac{3.1V - 2.4V}{1mA} \\ \\
R_2 &= 700\Omega \\ \\
R_1 + R_2 &= 2600\Omega \\ \\
R_1 &= 2600\Omega - R_1 \\ \\
R_1 &= 1900\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Thank you very helpful
